# How to sum this condition in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Please help me i stuck in this condition for sum in crystal reports.
My data like this :

```
Code   Qty  Accumulation
A0001   1        1
A0002   3        4
A0003   5        9
```

I want the accumulation like above, what function or what formula to sum like that?

Please help me.

Comment: You want to sun 1st and 2nd rows but not 3rd? is that part you are looking into?

Comment: ops sorry all record until end.